# Can I install Linux on USB drive and then connect same drive internally (sata) and boot from it?

Tags: system-installation, bootable

I would like to replace the hard drive in an old (2013) laptop with a cheap SSD.

The SSD is empty and working AFAIK, it is seen by the BIOS and it's info are reported correctly, but if I turn the laptop on with it connected, it doesn't allow me to boot from any peripherals, no matter how I change the bios settings, boot override etc. If I remove it, I can easily boot from usb or cd/dvd.

So, the idea is...

1. buy one of those sata to USB adapters, turning the SSD in a portable USB drive
2. boot the pc from cd
3. Install the system (Debian) onto the SSD through usb
4. Put the SSD back inside the laptop

Would this work? How likely is that the installer sees the USB drive as a good target for the installation? Assuming the original issue was not caused by compatibility problem with the bios, and that the installation could be done through usb, would switching the drive from usb to sata result in a bootable system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to unix.SE.

Your plan is likely to work unless the machine's BIOS is very weird.

> Would this work?

I expect it to.

> How likely is that the installer sees the usb drive as a good target for the installation?

Very likely.

> Assuming the original issue was not caused by compatibility problem with the bios, and that the installation could be done through usb, would switching the drive from usb to sata result in a bootable system?

Yes.

Note: You can even use a entirely different machine to perform the installation and then "transplant" the SSD. The CPU architecture (i386/amd64) and boot style (UEFI/BIOS) should be the same, though.

Comment: I wasn't able to boot from the SSD once I plugged it back (SATA) after the installation was done but I discovered it to be an incompatibility issue with my specific SSD model. The procedure itself would have worked so I'm accepting this answer.